# android setting activity orientation by code

Tags: android, screen, orientation

it is possible to set the orientation of an activity in the manifest file.

but is it also possible to do it from code? if so, how?

thanks!

Comment: [Activity. setRequestedOrientation(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int))

Comment: thanks, do you also know if it is possible to keep the activity locked in this orientation no matter how the device is tilted?

Comment: @Clamp implement it in the same Manner as the Cristian has written the code above

Comment: afaik only through manifest file

Comment: if i call setRequestedOrientation it still calls onResume, when the device is tilted. what value should i put in the manifest file?

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

Answer (score 26):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: thanks, do you also know if it is possible to keep the activity locked in this orientation no matter how the device is tilted?

Comment: FWIW to force the activity into a single orientation you can use this
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`
in your AndroidManifest.xml on any activities you want to lock.

Comment: And how to do it programatically, Brett? If I add a "Lock screen orientation" in my settings or menu, it would be nice to be able to do it.